# PHP mail form not working unless I use CAPTCHA

Tags: php, email, forms

I am trying to get this form to send to my email address.

Here is the PHP I am using (it is for the form located on http://protoolstutorial.org/cottageinn/). I need to know why this isn't going through and sending to my email. What am I missing from the code?

```
<?php 

$your_email ='cottageinndrive@gmail.com';// <<=== update to your email address

session_start();

$errors = '';
$south = '';
$east = '';
$west = '';
$midwest = '';
$visitor_email = '';

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $south = $_POST['south'];
    $east = $_POST['east'];
    $west = $_POST['west'];
    $midwest = $_POST['midwest'];
    $visitor_email = $_POST['email'];

    ///------------Do Validations-------------

    if(empty($visitor_email))
    {
        $errors .= "\n Email is required fields. "; 
    }

    if(IsInjected($visitor_email))
    {
        $errors .= "\n Bad email value!";
    }

    if(empty($errors))
    {
        //send the email
        $to = $your_email;
        $subject="New form submission";
        $from = $your_email;
        $ip = isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) ? $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] : '';
        $body = "A user  submitted the contact form:\n".
                "South: $south\n".
                "East: $east\n".
                "West: $west\n".
                "Midwest: $midwest\n".
                "Email: $visitor_email \n".
                "IP: $ip\n";    
        $headers = "From: $from \r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";

        mail($to, $subject, $body,$headers);
        header('Location: thank-you.html');
    }
}

// Function to validate against any email injection attempts
function IsInjected($str)
{
    $injections = array('(\n+)', 
                        '(\r+)', 
                        '(\t+)', 
                        '(%0A+)', 
                        '(%0D+)', 
                        '(%08+)', 
                        '(%09+)'
                       );
    $inject = join('|', $injections);
    $inject = "/$inject/i";
    if(preg_match($inject,$str))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you trying to send from localhost? Like xampp?

Comment: To help yourself, write "var_dump($errors);" before "if(empty($errors))" :)

Comment: jsut adding var_dump doesn't fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add `error_reporting(E_ALL)` at the beginning of your php to get errors.
2. Declare functions before using them.
3. For smart, safe and easy mail sending, try http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/

Comment: really? that doesn't help at all? It's a link to a bunch of downloads...

Comment: Does php returns any errors after adding error_reporting(E_ALL) at the beginning of the file?

Comment: could the problem be that the post can't pick up data from a dropdown select html element?

Comment: add `die()` before `header('Location: thank-you.html');`. Also add `var_dump('test');` after entering first if, to determine that script enters it. Move forward thorugh rest of the code with `var_dump` to control flow of your code.